# How to create a randomized world background pattern from a single PNG image?

Tags: texturing, shaders, world

I'd like to create a custom world background set in space, using a single PNG file and randomizing its size and placements. The PNG is of a simple vector star that I would to turn into many stars in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a UV sphere, in its material, plug an *Image Texture* into an *Emission*, create a new image that is black or white and 2:1 proportion (for example 1024x512):

[image]

Switch to *Texture Paint* mode, under *Tool > Brush Settings > Texture*, load your star texture, switch the *Mapping* to *Stencil*:

[image]

Paint the stars on the sphere:

[image]

Switch the *Shader Editor* to *World*, plug an *Environment Texture* node into the *Background* node, select the image you've created, switch to *Perspective* node in your 3D view, you'll see the image as background:

[image]

There's a limit with this method though, as the UV sphere UVs is not the same as the world UV, you'll have problem on the poles:

[image]

What you could is switch to Cycles, put your camera inside the sphere, in the camera *Object Data* panel choose *Lens > Panoramic* and *Type > Equirectangular*, in the *Output* panel > *Format* > choose a 2:1 proportion image, under *Output > File Format* > choose *Radiance HDR*, render, you've got your HDRI image.